# Creating dashed lines in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, line, style

I know [Line dash not working OL3 (Openlayers 3)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127624) has been asked earlier but the solution proposed is not working.

My code is :

```js
var calculateStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [255, 255, 255, 0.6],
                    opacity: 0.3
                }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [0, 153, 255, 1],
                    inedash: [40,40],
                    width: 3
                })
});
```

I tried both `[4,4]` and `[40,40]` suggested in the question linked. But it's not working.

Comment: please try `lineDash: [4,4]` or `lineDash: [40,40]`

Comment: @GaborFarkas : Hi. I already tried both but it's not working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Dashed lines can be done with:

```js
new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 3,
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        lineDash: [.1, 5] //or other combinations
    }),
    zIndex: 2
})
```

I've made you an online example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AW1YNC?p=preview

You can use this online "tester" to get various combinations http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_dashed_line.html

Comment: Good Live Example but can you describe in your answer what you did to get the dashed lines?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I got the mistake. I've been doing the same thing everyone's telling me to do. The mistake was a small difference of lower case and upper case characters. 'Linedash' and 'LineDash'